# How can metal workers dip their hands into molten lava without injury?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-conductivity

According to Halliday-Resnick, metal workers have observed that they can dip a hand very briefly into hot molten metal without ill effects.

A quick Google query pulls up responses based on the Leidenfrost effect, but to my knowledge this effect only occurs due to a water vapor "shield" of sorts forming. Yet, the question seems to imply that it is not necessary to dip the hand into a bucket of water first. How is this possible?

Comment: heat transfer did not happen instantly at classical level, even in qm it took a measurement as well. Plus there was sweat on the skin surface.

Comment: Well, there is water stored in human flesh -- besides oils and stuff on the skin. Dipping your hand in water first makes sure that you have *more* water available. Obligatory 'do no try at home' warning.

Comment: Won't find many physicists trying this, including I suspect Halliday et al. :-)  For every one who got away with doing this there are probably ten more more than got badly hurt, you just don't hear about the ones that are hurt - [Survivorship Bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias).

Comment: Dipping into liquid gallium will be unlikely to do much harm. Splashes of eutectic Pb-Sn solder are somewhat painful but not very damaging to the skin. Rapid dunking of fingers in LN2 is possible. None of these should be intentionally tried at home (much less at work).

Comment: Which 'hot molten metal'?